# How to create a custom date period slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

Is it possible to have single selection radio buttons slicer that would filter by Today() - 7 days, Today() - 30 days and Today() - 60 days?  So, to plot the last 7 days values, 30 days values or 60 days values.  I'm able to single select by Quarters but instead of quarters use a range of days based on today's date?  I tried filters but didn't get it to work.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [check this out](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/custom-range-date-slicer-power-bi-dynamic-defaults-more-a%C5%9F%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu/) and you can adjust according to your values...

Comment: Great link @UmutK

Comment: Thank you Umut K.  That is a great example website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a **calculated table**:

```
Date Periods = 
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 7, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 7 days",
        "Sort", 1
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 30, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 30 days",
        "Sort", 2
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 60, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 60 days",
        "Sort", 3
    )
)
```

2. Sort the **Period** column by the **Sort** column
3. Create a **bi-directional relationship** between 'Date Periods'[Date] and your days
4. Add 'Date Periods'[Period] to a slicer and set the selection settings to **Single select**

The result should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice and neat! Why bi-directional? Isn't one-directional sufficient?

Comment: You're right, a one-directional filter from 'Date Periods' to the days would be sufficient, but you can only configure it that way for many-to-many relationships. If you have a setup like in the question - or if you are using a separate Date table - you  have a one-to-many relationship  that doesn't allow changing the filter direction to just many-to-one. So you have to select bi-directional filtering, even if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Exactly what we needed!

Comment: You can force the relationship to be many-to-many and one-way filter @Peter!

Answer (score 0):

It shows this.

"The expression refers to several columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

I really did not understand

Comment: You should edit your question or answer with a comment rather than answering the question.